# Duplicate Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types

My Theme has special meta panels to custom post. What I want to do is Clone the Post type and create another Post type with same functions so that I can control new post type differently.
Simply Clone Post to new Post type Post_2 with all the meta panels.
can anyone tell me how to do that?
I created the custom post with Custom post UI but I am unable to get post meta panels to new post type.

Comment: How are the meta boxes added? Is it coded in or do you use something like http://advancedcustomfields.com

Comment: It is coded in theme.

Comment: Have you asked the theme support/developers?